# Get third party loggedin user data in Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I'm developing an app and successfully made the login with Google. The problem is that I have no idea on how to get the user email at least.

What I have done previously:
First I experimented with the default user login "framework" which can be selected on project creation and then I added the third party login. The problem is that too many tables are created with that method and i only need one table for the user data. I also want to be me to decide which columns there will be in the user table. Also, with that login method I get redirected to a razor page to make the login, and then I'm redirected back to the blazor app again. Which is not very pretty since I only want to make the login with google.

Situation now:
I'm replicating the login of this repo so I don't get redirected to a razor page to make the login:
https://github.com/dotnet-presentations/blazor-workshop

I changed the startup to add Google to options:

```
services
                .AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddCookie()
                .AddTwitter(twitterOptions =>
                {
                    twitterOptions.ConsumerKey = Configuration["Authentication:Twitter:ConsumerKey"];
                    twitterOptions.ConsumerSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Twitter:ConsumerSecret"];
                    twitterOptions.Events.OnRemoteFailure = (context) =>
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        return context.Response.WriteAsync("<script>window.close();</script>");
                    };
                })
            .AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
             {
                 googleOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
                 googleOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
                 googleOptions.Events.OnRemoteFailure = (context) =>
                 {
                     context.HandleResponse();
                     return context.Response.WriteAsync("<script>window.close();</script>");
                 };
             });
```

In blazor app I have the link to login in:

```
<a class="sign-in" href="user/signin">Sign in</a>
```

In the server I have:

```
[HttpGet("user/signin")]
        public async Task SignIn(string redirectUri)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(redirectUri) || !Url.IsLocalUrl(redirectUri))
            {
                redirectUri = "/";
            }

            await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(
                Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google
                .GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUri });
            
        }
```

So, how do I get the user data from this point in the server?

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

When accessing a protected recource on the server, usually an API to get data from, we somehow will have the autenticated user data under "User" variable by defining @using Microsoft.AspnetCore.Authorization.
Here is an example with the email captured on the bottom:

```
[Route("orders")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize]
    // [Authorize]
    public class OrdersController : Controller
    {
        private readonly PizzaStoreContext _db;

        public OrdersController(PizzaStoreContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<OrderWithStatus>>> GetOrders()
        {
            string g = User.Identity.Name;
            string email = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
```

With that i can get the user id on the users table and get any kind of that that i want from the database.
I also would like que get the profile picture from google...

################################

Edited:
To do so just add this option on startup file inside the google service

```
googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("profilepic", "picture");
```

And then we  can gab the email like so in a protected resource in the server

```
string pic = User.FindFirstValue("profilepic");
```

Now i would like to know how to grab the profile picture on the client side....